# Difference between ReadOnlyObservableCollection and ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, observablecollection

What is the difference between `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` and `ObservableCollection`?

I have the following code snippet:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<FeedData> _Feeds = new ObservableCollection<FeedData>();
public ObservableCollection<FeedData> Feeds
{
    get
    {
        return this._Feeds;
    }
}
```

Can I replace `ObservableCollection` with `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding to the _Feeds when it's a **ReadOnly** Collection.

It's a wrapper that prevents you from changing the collection. Of course its just a wrapper so if you have  reference to the underlying collection, you can by pass the **ReadOnly**

The clue is in the name.

Answer (score 1):

`ReadOnlyObservableCollection` is a readonly wrapper over `ObservableCollection`.

No changes can be made through this readonly wrapper but all the changes to underlying ObservableCollection are reflected to ReadOnlyObservableCollection.

If ObservableCollection is not exposed as ReadOnly (not the readonly property, but as ReadOnlyObservableCollection), the underlying collection is exposed to modification.

> > Arrays returned by properties are not write-protected, even if the property is read-only. To keep the array tamper-proof, the property must return a copy of the array. Typically, users will not understand the adverse performance implications of calling such a property. Specifically, they might use the property as an indexed property.

[CA1819: Properties should not return arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx)